# Output \thanks under authors in \maketitle

Tags: titles

How can one typeset the associations under the authors, by means of `\renewcommand{\maketitle}{}` or using the `titling` package? I'm trying to get something like this:

[image: Image of the desired title]

### What I have so far

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{A very fancy title}
\author{John Doe\thanks{University of Doeland}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
  \renewcommand*\footnoterule{}
  {\Large\bfseries\@title}\par
  \medskip
  \@author\par
  \medskip
  \@thanks % adding \@thanks here causes the footnote to be typeset at the bottom of the page
  \medskip
  \hline
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a minimal working example (MWE).

Comment: @Bobyandbob there you go.

Comment: Why don't you use the journal's class?

Comment: The image is just an example I found, @cfr. I'm not actually submitting any papers, but would like to learn how changing the position of the footnotes can be accomplished.

Comment: what you show for "thanks" looks terribly like an institutional address.  take a look for how to enter an author address with the `article` document class.  that may be what you are looking for.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I didn't know `article` had addresses… I only know of the `\thanks` command.

Answer (score 3):

`\maketitle` is one of the most confused commands. It only makes sense for repeated articles that shall keep the same appearance.

I suggest not to use it for single papers or articles.

[image: bobcat]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
{\Huge\bfseries How to use a Wheelie Bin?\par\vspace{2\baselineskip}}
Walter Wombat\textsuperscript{1}, Carl Capybara\textsuperscript{2}, Bill Bobcat, Samantha Salamander, Quintus Quail, and Rusty Racoon
\par\vspace{\baselineskip}
\textsuperscript{1} University of Trash Cans\par \url{www.donotwasteyourtime.com}\par \url{walter@carpediem.org}\par
\textsuperscript{2} National Institute of Waste
\end{center}
\tableofcontents
\section{The wheels}
\section{the lid}

\end{document}
```